# Word for “decorated too much”

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word (verb) meaning decorate/embellish too much — in a bad sense — and in particular having the tint of being too much so that something instead of being beautiful becomes fussy and ugly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of any better single verbs than *overdecorate*, *overornament* or *overembellish*.  *Bedizen* is good if you don't mind obscure.  I might be tempted to coin *baroquify*.  Related, possibly useful phrases include *to tart [something] up* and *gilding the lily*.

Comment: I like "bedizen." I'm not sure when I would ever use it, but I like it. I can very easily imagine using "baroquify," but I do like making up words. :)

Comment: If you're going to coin go with *"Rococoinate"*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I very much liked the idiom *gilding the lily*; I found the definition here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gilding+the+lily (bedizen is not exactly what I was looking for).

Comment: Note: dictionaries list *bedizen* as *archaic*.

Comment: @chaos first read that as *bedazzled*.

Comment: "Gilding the lily" would work only if you had something perfect to begin with.  If you overdecorated a McMansion, "tart up" is better.

Answer (score 11):

Adjectivally, you could describe something as ***baroque***:

> extravagantly ornate, florid, and convoluted in character or style
>    <sub>from *[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/baroque?s=t)*</sub>

or ***florid***:

> flowery; excessively ornate; showy
>    <sub>from *[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/florid?s=t)*</sub>

Verbwise, I can't think of any single word that encompasses that extent of a description, unless you want to go for something like *overembellished* with an additional phrase to point out how far beyond the pale it's gone:  "He had overembellished it to the point that it became a grotesque parody of its potential nature", or "he had embellished it well past the point of baroque floridity."

Comment: However, do note that baroque is period and style, and as such the extravagance of some of the better works would be considered positive (at least by some; example: Trevi Fountain in Rome)

Answer (score 5):

How about gaudy?

> **gaud·y**
>   –adjective, gaud·i·er, gaud·i·est.
>   1.
>   brilliantly or excessively showy: gaudy plumage.
>   2.
>   cheaply showy in a tasteless way; flashy.
>   3.
>   ostentatiously ornamented; garish.

Comment: I think *gaudy* is a fine adjective, but the asker is looking for a verb.

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: @John Well then gaudify, obviously. ;)

Comment: The title is "Word for 'decorated too much'," not only a verb.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the verb "overdo." What exactly has been overdone is usually pretty obvious. Saying something is really overdone usually means it's tacky or overwrought, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually one word to refer specifically to this.  It's ["kitsch":](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kitsch)

> a representation that is excessively sentimental, overdone, or vulgar

Comment: Also recommended is to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsch to *see* if the word fits. Note: 1926, from Ger., lit. "gaudy, trash," from dial. kitschen "to smear."

Comment: Also consider *overwrought*. Kitsch suggests overly cute or junky; the word sought may be just too much of a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

How about `garish`?

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

> garish
>         adj 1: tastelessly showy; "a flash car"; "a flashy ring";
>                "garish colors"; "a gaudy costume"; "loud sport shirts";
>                "a meretricious yet stylish book"; "tawdry ornaments"
>                [syn: {brassy}, {cheap}, {flash}, {flashy}, {garish},
>                {gaudy}, {gimcrack}, {loud}, {meretricious}, {tacky},
>                {tatty}, {tawdry}, {trashy}]

Answer (score 1):

"baroquify" is a contrived verb that I first heard in computer science circles 40+ years ago.

I just ran across this post when I used the word in a gmail body and was surprised that the spellchecker didn't flag it, so I did a search.

Comment: ...and, yes, it means what you want it to...

Answer (score 0):

Make gaudy... over-decorate.

Maybe bedeck

Answer (score 0):

Rococo is another term that might apply. Although more in reference to painting, it conveys the sense of gingerbread which this question addresses.

Comment: This would be improved with a reference/definition for the term.

Comment: Is this some use of "gingerbread" with which I'm not familliar?

Comment: I've just gone through all the answers, downvoting all those that don't bother addressing OP's request for a **verb**. This is yet another.

Answer (score -1):

The word that springs to mind is: Overdecorated.

Answer (score -1):

the word you seek is ungapatchka.  (it's yiddish)

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ungapatchka):

> a Yiddish word that describes the overly ornate, busy, ridiculously
>   over-decorated, and garnished to the point of distaste.
>
> the clothing looks ungapatchka.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. StackExchange seeks *definitive* answers, and yours would be greatly strengthened by *explaining* this word. How is it used? Is it in the dictionary? What are some examples of its use? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: The 'patch' part matches the English word 'patch.' Ungepatchka means made into a patchwork, pieced together poorly rather than being of a whole elegant work.

Answer (score -2):

well i guess you could use the word bedeck.

for example my friend john led me to his room bedecked with green marbles

Comment: I'm not sure that "bedeck" carries any sense of _too much_ decoration.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from linked references to support that meaning of bedeck.

Answer (score -2):

**Shmonzes** means valueless stuff--used for objects

> small pieces of valueless decorative bric-a-brac; idle talk
> (Yiddish origin, [jel.jewish-languages](https://jel.jewish-languages.org/words/1624)).

Schmates is for raggedy clothes.

Comment: This would be greatly improved with some linked authoritative definitions for these words

Comment: Hello, 4078, welcome to EL&U! You should improve this answer with referenced and linked definitions showing definitions or examples of the usage of shmonzes and shmates in an English context. I've suggested one for shmonzes (which you can still edit if you like), but I didn't find one for shmates, I'll leave it for you. [Long, articulate answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are encouraged here. Cheers! (Oh, and OP asked for a verb...)

Answer (score -3):

*Ragged* or *shabby* means unattractive. When a more complex decoration is applied to something it becomes *ugly*. It doesn't look *professionally made*.